# Why some Bundle objects will update by reference and some not?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, parcelable

I have a fragment and I create a new Instance of it, in my Activity, Also I'm passing a Parcelable data class to the fragment like this:

```
fun newInstance(
            use: User,
            date: Date
        ): CalendarDialogFragment {
            val fragment = MyFragment()
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putParcelable("user", user)
            bundle.putSerializable("date", date)
            fragment.arguments = bundle
            return fragment
        }
```

And in the fragment I want to use it like this:

```
var user =  arguments?.getParcelable("user")
var date =  arguments?.getSerializable("date")
```

This is a normal way of passing data to fragments.
because of shallow copy, When I change this user object and update its field in the fragment, the bundle object will be updated too.
But for some objects like the `Date` (java.util) type, it's not happening. For example, if I pass a `Date` to the fragment and do the same, the bundle object of date will not update like the user object, I think I'm missing something here!?

Answer (score 0):

Here you would need to make a deep copy of the user, i.e., a copy that doesn't copy references, but actually copies the object the references are pointing at.
I think you need to understand deep copy and shallow copy. You can read it here
[What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I know the difference between copies, But when I pass Date and User,
I'm using a shallow copy for both of them so I expect that the date and user object in the bundle will update by the reference but it's not happened for Date object and I don't know why